# Postgresql row level security, for in many to many relation, for insert statement

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

[image]

I want to insert data into user_group table. But how do I verify that user belongs to tenant of corresponding group.

In our system a user can be part of multiple tenants and under one tenant that user can be part of multiple groups. Now how can I create a policy for `user_group` on insert to check if user has a role assigned in current tenant. Role assignment can be checked via user_role table.

I'm new to using RLS and this is how I tried creating a policy for this tabel

```
CREATE POLICY insert_user_group_policy ON user_group FOR INSERT TO public 
WITH CHECK((SELECT user_role.id FROM user_role WHERE user_role.tenant_id = current_setting('app.tenant_id')::int) = user_id);

ALTER TABLE user_group ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

Comment: Can you explain your schema a bit? How does a user belong to a tenant? It looks like your users can belong to multiple tenants, is that right?

Comment: Your RLS policy uses a `user_group.tenant_id` column, but that does not exist in your schema?

Comment: Do you already have working policies for actions other than `INSERT`?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry. I edited the sql. It was supposed to be user_role not user_group. Also, I added few more details about how the system will work.

Comment: What's the problem with your current policy? You're getting an error, right?

Comment: No. It allows me to add user, in user_group, that is not part of current tenant.

Comment: You really should be getting an error since the subselect in the policy does select *all* user ids that have any role in the tenant, and you cannot compare that to a single value. What you need is at least an `EXISTS` clause

Comment: OK. So after re-reading your previous comments. I checked if any other policies were being applied to this table and there was one with `FOR ALL` actions. I removed that policy and changed check function to
`CHECK(user_id in (SELECT user_role.id FROM user_role WHERE user_role.tenant_id = current_setting('app.tenant_id')::int) AND team_id in (SELECT id FROM "Team" WHERE tenant_id = current_setting('app.tenant_id')::int));`